# Printing Lists in python

Tags: python, list, printing

I am having issues trying to print a list in python. I want to print out all of the items in a list with the following code, specifically the last two lines.

```
def primefind(n):
  mylist = []
  x = 3
  while (x < n/2):
    if ((n % x) == 0):
      mylist.append(x)
      x = x + 2
  for item in mylist:
    print item
```

I am getting a syntax error when I run this. It highlights "item" in the last line. As far as I can tell it's syntactically correct so I am confused! Even this site shows the same syntax as I've used http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#looping

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is a typo but it looks like you need to move the x = x + 2 out of the if block

Comment: Yea that's just a typo. Good catch though.

Comment: You don't need parentheses around conditions in `if` and `while` statements in Python.

Comment: @Daniel My old C habits showing through. I think it reads clearer with parenthesis. But that may just be because of what i'm used to.

Comment: @user1322388: Python has a style guide called [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  Most people stick to this style guide, which has the advantage that most Python code uses a familiar style, increasing readability.

Comment: @Sven Thanks I shall check it out. I really must try and get out of bad habits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using Python 2.x syntax with a 3.x interpreter.  `print` is a function in Python 3.x, so you should use

```
print(item)
```

instead.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I'm new to python so I really need to get used to things changing so much between versions!